# Is there any way to execute python unittests with a test suite from PyCharm?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I'm trying to run some unittest from PyCharm, but I would like to use TestSuites, so that if I need to deactivate one test I could do it.

Here I have a simple code example of what I'm doing:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest import TestSuite
from unittest import TextTestRunner
from unittest import defaultTestLoader


class DummyTestOne(TestCase):
    def test_execute(self):
        x, y, expected_result = 10, 5, 15

        self.assertEqual(x + y, expected_result)


class DummyTestTwo(TestCase):
    def test_execute(self):
        x, y, expected_result = 10, 5, 50

        self.assertEqual(x * y, expected_result)


suite = defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(DummyTestOne)
TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

So that if I execute it from a cmd like this `python test_testingWithTestSuites.py`, I get executed just the TestCase I want, but if I execute it directly from PyCharm it is still running both TestCases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into using pyTest? I think you can just run `pytest` and it will run all tests for a given project (from what little I remember). Used it years ago and it worked well enough.

Comment: Normally, you can run a selected test class or method by clicking the respective green arrow in the gutter, and clicking `Run 'Unittests for ...'`. This will create a temporary run configuration that you can subsequently quickly access and re-run with the Ctrl-F10 shortcut.

Comment: Yes both ideas are ok, I could use ```pytest``` as I can run it from a cmd as a simple python script, and on the other hand I can also run it with Pycharm as mportes says.

But that's not exactly what I want, I would like to know why executing it from cmd it does what I want (just executing one of the testcases which is added in the testsuite) and if I run it from PyCharm it does not

Comment: @josecgon Please note that when running tests in PyCharm by hitting Ctrl-Shift-F10, it depends where you text cursor (caret) is positioned. If inside a test method, only this method will run. If inside a class but not inside a method, only tests from this class will run. If in the top-level code, all tests in the script will run.

Comment: Yes I know, but that is not what I really want to do. For example I want to write tests to be run in a regression test suite automatically, but I know that "DummyTestTwo" cannot be executed (or it is not just useful), so I want to remove it from the execution removing it from the Test Suite, but not from the code